# Using JS React component in TypeScript: JSX element type 'MyComponent' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, single-page-application

I'm working with a JavaScript legacy project which uses React framework. We have there some React component defined which I'd like to re-use in a totally different TypeScript React project.

The JS React component is defined in controls.jsx file and looks as follows:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hi from MyComponent! Message provided: {this.props.message}</h1>;
  }
}
```

In my TypeScript React project I'm trying to use it like that:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MyComponent } from "../JavaScriptProject/controls";

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent message="some nice message"/>,
    document.getElementById("documents-tree")
);
```

but I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Error messages say:

> JSX element type 'MyComponent' is not a constructor function for JSX
>   elements.   Type 'MyComponent' is missing the following properties
>   from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2
>   more.ts(2605) JSX element class does not support attributes because it
>   does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)

I've already tried the solution with custom typings file described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540536/react-using-es6-component-in-ts-component-ts2605-jsx-element-type-xxx-is-no) question, but it changes nothing.

I understand that the JS component has some strongly-typed properties required by TypeScript missing, but in my tsconfig.json I have the **allowJs** set to *true*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "lib-amd"
  ]
}
```

so I hoped it should work...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try these solutions -> https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/21242 ?

Comment: I tried, but nothing helps... I don't use yarn so few of them were irrelevant. The others don't help at all...

Comment: It works fine for me without any issue. i just created a typescript app and added the controls.jsx file at src.

Comment: Hmm... so maybe it's a matter of some npm packages? Or their versions? Could you share your tsconfig.json, package.json and maybe webpack.config.js?

Comment: this sounds a lot like you have mismatched react and react-dom typings. can you share your package-lock & package.json? you may need to place package-lock on pastebin/gist due to its length.

Comment: Sure - package.json: https://pastebin.com/Eq0YPsCN, package-lock.json: https://pastebin.com/0ffN2PzF

Comment: Hmm. Do you only get this error in your editor? Is it still present when you compile using the command line?

Comment: how about set compiler option allowSyntheticDefaultImports to true.

Comment: @DanPantry I'm getting the error also when compiling using the command line.

Comment: @RollingPanda it doesn't help at all

Answer (score 2):

You should turn `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` since React does not export default.

(source: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/index.js)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // turn on allowSyntheticDefaultImports
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "lib-amd"
  ]
}
```

Also, you should add the shape for component props. For example, in your code:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component<{ message: string }> { ...
```

Comment: Thank for answering. Setting `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to `true` changes nothing, I'm still getting the same error. I can't add shape for components props, because it's defined in a .jsx file and I'm getting the following error: "'type arguments' can only be used in a .ts file.ts(8011)"

Answer (score 0):

Here are the configs for you reference which i am using in my sample application.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have not used webpack.

Comment: Even if I take your configs it doesn't help... :/

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options:

1. You can supply a declarations file in the same directory as `controls.jsx` named `controls.t.ds`.

This options has two ways of going about it. The easiest is just to export a function with the name of `MyComponent`:

```js
export function MyComponent(): any;
```

The second is to export a variable that mimics the class structure of a component:

```js
interface Element {
    render(): any;
    context: any;
    setState: any;
    forceUpdate: any;
    props: any;
    state: any;
    refs: any;
}

interface MyComponent extends Element {}

export var MyComponent: {
    new(): MyComponent;
}
```

2. Your second option is to import your component and re-export it with a type definition. This file would be included somewhere within project:

```
import React from 'react';
import {MyComponent as _MyComponent} from '../project-a/Controls';

interface MyComponent extends React.Component {}

const MyComponent = (_MyComponent as any) as {
    new(): MyComponent;
};

export {MyComponent};
```

And then in your file that wants to use `MyComponent`, you would import it from that new file instead.

These are all really gross solutions, but I believe it's the only solution as TypeScript doesn't let you define a module that is relative to your project:

```js
declare module "../project/Controls" {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the option 2 and I declared this extra file, additionally adding a `message` of `string` type to the component (`MyComponent extends React.Component<{ message: string }>` and VS Code doesn't give me any errors when importing this component from the new file. However, I'm still getting a compile error in the new file: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../JS_TS_Project/Scripts/application/controls'`

Comment: @DawidSibiński What packager are you using? Metro, babel, WebPack?

Comment: I'm using webpack

Comment: @DawidSibiński I believe you'll have to tell Webpack to include the JS_TS_Project in it's include resolution. See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257787/701263

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, but still can't get it to work... I gave up a bit, cause finally, I used a separate TS component. However, the issue still remains open and interesting. Even if one of these solutions worked, this is still tight-coupling both modules/projects and far from a reliable and re-usable solution.